# Read 1 gb text file character wise and insert in to db

Tags: console

I have 1GB text file and I have a temp table with id and name and I want to read first 182 characters from text file and insert in to db then next 182 character and insert in to db. What is the best way to achieve this, any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When the amount of data that you want to read is fixed, you can read these 182 bytes at once and repeat it in a while or for loop.

Here is a little demo written in AS3:

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file,FileMode.READ);

    var data:ByteArray;
    var bytesRead:int = 0;
    while(stream.bytesAvailable >= 182){
        stream.readBytes(data,bytesRead,182);
        bytesRead += 182;
        // do stuff with read data
    }

    stream.close();
```

It would be possible ti itterate through the read data in the while loop if necessary:

```
while(stream.bytesAvailable >= 182){
        stream.readBytes(data,bytesRead,182);
        bytesRead += 182;
        data.position=0;
        while(data.bytesAvailable > 0){
            data.readUnsignedByte();
            ...
        }

 }
```

Edit:
When you have such a big amount of data it is a good idea to process these in a extra Thread.

Comment: i need console application in c#